# Finding key/value in redis

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I have written a simple node/express/redis app, that stores a custom session id in redis. It works. But being new to redis, I'm only able to locate the `sessionID`, but not `jsessionid` in redis.

```
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
    host: redisHost,
    port: redisPort,
    db: redisDB
});

app.use(session({
    name: 'jsessionid', // access using req.cookies['jsessionid']
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    store: sessionStore
}));

app.get('/awesome', function(req, res) {
    if(req.session.lastPage) {
        res.write('Last page was: ' + req.session.lastPage + '. And session id was: ' + req.sessionID + '. And jsessionid is ' + req.cookies['jsessionid'] + '. ');
    }
    req.session.lastPage = '/awesome';
    res.end('Your Awesome.');
});
```

So, when I do `http://localhost:3000/awesome` and reload it, then it prints out the following as expected:

"Last page was: /awesome. And session id was: kOnhpfyFQlil76eVXIbIBJTUNU7GzhDG. And jsessionid is s:kOnhpfyFQlil76eVXIbIBJTUNU7GzhDG.KF3B6TLxMl084VI2rvYw+hz4u/wQr5IL7n+//gnH9mQ. Your Awesome."

And I can find the sessionID in `redis-cli` by doing:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> select 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> keys *
1) "sess:kOnhpfyFQlil76eVXIbIBJTUNU7GzhDG"
```

But I"m unable to find the `jsessionid` in redis. I think it should exist somewhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` option for the `express-session` middleware is only the name of the cookie. You can change the *prefix* though by setting the `prefix` option (defaults to `'sess:'`) in your `RedisStore` config. See [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/connect-redis#options) for more options you can set.

Comment: I have treated sessionID and jsessionid at the same level, as far as them getting set in redis. So, why does the `sess` prefix show sessionID, instead of jsessionid ?

Comment: I assume that the sessionID key stores the jsessionid in it. Try doing GET or HGET (depending the data type in use) on the sessionID key.